# Mix Node's CommonJS and Typescript's ES modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-modules, commonjs

I have a legacy app in Node.js v10 (but upgrading is an option) which uses CommonJS modules (require).
The codebase is written in JS.
Now, I want to refactor **part** of the project and write it in Typescript using TS modules (import/export) and classes.
What is the best way to interface those newly generated JS files (compiled from TS) from my legacy JS code?

Say I have a class in TS:

```
export default class DemoClass {

public static sayHello() {
    console.log("Hello from demo class...");
}
```

}

which gets compiled to:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var DemoClass = /** @class */ (function () {
    function DemoClass() {
    }
    DemoClass.sayHello = function () {
        console.log("Hello from demo class...");
    };
    return DemoClass;
}());
exports.default = DemoClass;
//# sourceMappingURL=DemoClass.js.map
```

I have set "module": "commonjs" in my tsconfig.json.

Now, how do I require that DemoClass.js from my legacy app.js and e.g. invoke sayHello()?
The following code seems to work, but this "default" stuff does not seem right:

```
var DemoClass = require('./lib/DemoClass');
DemoClass.default.sayHello();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `export default`, use `export =`.

```
export = class DemoClass {
    public static sayHello() {
        console.log("Hello from demo class...");
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?esModuleInterop=false&module=1&isolatedModules=false&allowSyntheticDefaultImports=false#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAXjgYwDYEMDOm4BFgC2EAwhtnAN4BQctcYArgEaoCWycmM6M7n6ATwASwVKggAKAJSUadecggA7TBFTAAdOIDmEgEQixEOADMoEAnAAmhY2iyYNTvVIDcc2gF8qnoA)

Comment: True, now that I knew what to search for, the "export =",  I've managed to find the relevant docs, so here they are if anybody else needs them:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require